# Creating QScatterSerie with for loop

Tags: c++, algorithm, qt, qstring

I need to create several QScatterSeries with for loopand I need to named them seperately. Here is the sample of my alghoritm :

```
 for(int serie_count=0;serie_count<50;serie_count++){
        QString machine_name = QString::number(serie_count);
        QString serie= "serie";
        QString serie_low = serie.append(machine_name);

        QScatterSeries *serie_low = new QScatterSeries();
```

But it gives me error because I previously declared serie_low as a string so I cant declare it as a QScatterSeries. Is there any way to do that? Any help will be appreciated.thanks.

Comment: So use a different name for the string *or* the `QScatterSeries` pointer? Perhaps append `_string` to the string variable? Or think of its meaning and uses and name it after that?

Comment: I mean I want to create a qsactterserie in every loop so first round I need to create a QScatterserie named serie_0 then serie_1 etc.

Comment: how can it be C? Deleted C tag

Comment: I am getting an impression that maybe you want to declare a `QList<QScatterSeries>` container outside the loop and a `push_back(new QScatterSeries)` inside it.   But that's not your question at the moment

Comment: Actually I tried to declare an array at header file then reach the element of array at the loop :header file : QScatterSeries qsctrArr[255]; cpp file :QScatterSeries this->qsctrArr[serie_count] = new QScatterSeries(); but it also gives me error.

Comment: Perhaps creating an array of `*QScatterSeries` is more what you wanted.  But using a container may be better in the long run

Comment: Are you really trying to access your collection given a string like 'ser-0', or merely by an integer OK?   You might have a wrong impression that you can create a new variable symbol using string operations, and that's not how C++ works

Comment: My priority was use "serie_count" in my qscatterserie name but for now reaching series by pointer of array is enough I can change the names of the series after. By the way header file : QScatterSeries *qsctrArr[255]; cpp file : this->qsctrArr[serie_count] = new QScatterSeries(); worked well for me thanks a lot.

Comment: If you need to create multiple objects and store them somehow, use a *container*. In plain C++ that would mena a `std::vector`. My question to you now is: Why didn't you think of it? Try to go through your own thoughts, and try to figure out why you forgot about containers (standard or Qt specific). When you wrapped your head around that, it will improve your skill as a programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments to the question, that it is desired to access a `QScatterSeries` object created in a loop, indexed by the loop number.  Can't test the code at the moment

```
QList<QScatterSeries> SSList;

for(int serie_count=0;serie_count<50;serie_count++)
{
   SSList.push_back(new QScatterSeries);
   QScatterSeries &currentSS= SSList[serie_count];

   // now do the rest of your loop code using currentSS as the iteration's QScatterSeries
   // use SSList[n] to access the QScatterSeries for loop n after the loop is over

}
```